# Jquery.get function being called infinite times when using custom header with XMLHttpRequest Open

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I have used custom header for each XMLHttpRequest as follows:

```
XMLHttpRequest.prototype.newOpen = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open;

XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = function(method, url) {
    var customValue = 'custom_value';
    this.newOpen.apply(this, arguments);
    this.setRequestHeader('X-Custom-Headers', customValue);
};
```

After that I am calling, Jquery's Get function as follows:

```
$(function(){
    var file = "location/somefile.csv";

    $.get(file, { "_": $.now() }, function(vals) {
        var csv_arr = $.csv.toArrays(vals);
        console.log(csv_arr);
    }).done(function() {
        alert("SUCCESS");
    }).error(function(err) {
        alert(err.statusText);
    });
})
```

But this $.get function is being called infinite times. When I remove custom header for all request, then it works.
I always get **Maximum call size exceeded** error.
Am I doing something wrong while setting custom header in `XMLHttpRequest`?
Or, what is causing my `$.get()` request being called infinite times?
Please help.

Comment: What calls that code of yours? For exampel is it on a button click, a page load etc?

Comment: @loan.burger It gets called on a page load. As you can see, the $.get() is called in $(function())

Answer (score 0):

I have not used JQuery for a while but depending where you want to all that code form e.g. when a button is clicked or a select option is changed etc. try putting your code in a namesa function like:

```
var csvHelper =
{
   readCsv: function() {
       var file = "location/somefile.csv";

        $.get(file, { "_": $.now() }, function(vals) {
         var csv_arr = $.csv.toArrays(vals);
         console.log(csv_arr);
       }).done(function() {
            alert("SUCCESS");
       }).error(function(err) {
    alert(err.statusText);
       });
   }
}
```

Then you call it on a button click or a page load like:

```
csvHelper.readCsv();
```

JSFiddle Example: https://jsfiddle.net/loanburger/1asngkt9/